# How do I post new string into a JPanel text field after the initial value has been set?

Tags: swing, textarea, jframe

I am trying to understand how the JFrame stuff works. I am writing a program, that will read the contents of a file, and display it into the text-area in the form of binary string. I have already accomplished the task in strict command prompt window format. Then, I realized that I needed to accomplish the task thru a JPane window. So, I have code thatI wrote, that allows the user to select a file for input, the code then checks for a valid file, and if it is there, then the code reads in a byte at a time, changes it into binary, and adds it to a string. After the entire file is read in, the string is displayed as a long binary in the command prompt. But I need to accomplish this task in the actual JFrame that I managed to create. But now, I cannot figure out where, and how, I am supposed to update the textarea with the string of binary info, after it is read in and created. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class BinaryEditor extends JFrame{

    public static String myExtension ="";
    public static boolean isThere=false;
    public static String myFile="";;
    public static String by;
    public static String myDisplay="";

//******************************************************************************

    public BinaryEditor(){

        //setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,10));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,5,5));
        //Set up panels for main display  
        JPanel fileInput = new JPanel(); 
        JPanel binaryPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel saveBinary = new JPanel();         

        //Add the panels to the frame 
        add(fileInput);
        add(binaryPanel);
        add(saveBinary);

        //Set up panel properties 
        fileInput.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        fileInput.setFont(new Font("Californian FB", Font.BOLD, 12));
        binaryPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        binaryPanel.setFont(new Font("Californian FB", Font.BOLD, 12));
        saveBinary.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        saveBinary.setFont(new Font("Californian FB", Font.BOLD, 12));  
        JTextField myDisplay = new JTextField(16);


        //Add contents to the panels
        fileInput.add(new JLabel("Enter a File"));
        fileInput.add(new JTextField(8));
        binaryPanel.add(new JTextArea("",10,22));
        saveBinary.add(new JButton("Save file"));
        binaryPanel.add(myDisplay);
    }

//******************************************************************************    

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Create a JFrame panel, set it up and display it
        BinaryEditor frame = new BinaryEditor();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setTitle("Binary Editor");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Ask user for filename
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        do{
        System.out.print("Please input a filename to read : ");
        myFile = input.next();

        //Validate filename and existance
        checkmyFile(myFile);
        if(!isThere)
            System.out.println("No such filename.");
        }while(!isThere);

        //File exists, now open file for reading
       readFile();
       System.out.println(myDisplay);
       repaint();
    }

//******************************************************************************    

    //Method to check filename
    public static boolean checkmyFile(String theFile){

        //Check for file existance
        File file=new File(theFile);
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        if (!exists) {
            isThere=false; 
        }else{
            isThere=true;
        }
        return isThere;
    }

//******************************************************************************    

    //Method to read file into array
    public static void readFile()throws IOException{
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        int numberBytes = myInput.available();
        byte bytearray[] = new byte[numberBytes];
        //Read entire file into bytearray
        myInput.read(bytearray);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberBytes; i++){
            //System.out.println (bytearray[i]);
            by = Integer.toBinaryString(bytearray[i]);
            //System.out.print(by+"*"); 
            myDisplay +=by;
        }
        myInput.close();
        //myDisplay.
    }  

}//End of MAIN Method
```

Answer (score 0):

First, yours JTextField needs to be declared as a class object, then you need to remove its declaration and instantiation from `BynaryEditor` constructor.

If you declare the JTextField in the constructor, it will be visible as method variable, not class variable, and, in the rest of your code, you won't able to invoke methods on it.

Second, once you read data from the file, you need to invoke the method [setText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) of the [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html), required to display the data from the file.

You can do that easily as:

```
public class BinaryEditor extends JFrame{
        /* class variable declaration and instantiation */

        private JTextField myDisplay = new JTextField(16);

        /* other code.. */
```

and, in your `readFile()` method, after the data reading, you can add the line:

```
myDisplay.setText(by);
```

In this way, your `by` string will be displayed in your JTextField.